# Sum of values in a has_many through - belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, belongs-to

In a Ruby on Rails 6.1 project I have `Users` that can pick a list of `Activities`. Each `Activity` has a `value`. I would like to get the total sum for all the Activities selected by all Users.

My Models are:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :activities, -> { distinct }, through: :user_activities
end
```

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, -> { distinct }, through: :user_activities
end
```

```
class UserActivity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

As mentioned, in the schema, `Activities` has an integer field that I called `value` and each activity has a value selected to it.

I managed to get the sum of all of the selected activities by all users using the following code but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
total_value = 0
UserActivity.all.each do |selected_user_activity|
  total_value += selected_user_activity.activity.value
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple if I understand you correctly.

```rb
sum_of_all_values = User.joins(:activities).sum('activities.value')
```